# Navigating in VS Code Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS code's Explorer side bar, how can I use `ctrl+p` and `ctrl+n` instead of up/down arrow keys for navigating among files?

Comment: Why do you want that? Those are some odd keys to choose...

Comment: I'm switching from Emacs, which uses those keys for navigating. By doing so I also don't have to move my hand away from home row.

Comment: Did you ever sort this? I'm tried of taking my hands off homerow

Comment: @CalebJay no, I gave up and went back to Emacs again.

Comment: Lol, funny, I was in the opposite field. Now I'm in a space where I have things I liked in emacs I'd like to get back to vscode, but emacs is too "much" to swap over to. Best of luck anyway.

Comment: @CalebJay if you still need this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your `keybindings.json` (you can find it by  `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command).

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "list.focusDown",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !inputFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "list.focusUp",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !inputFocus"
},
```